# Calling API with header from R

Tags: r, api, httr

I have an api like below. This code sample for Node.js. Without header it is easy to call an api from R but with header i could not do it. API address and header info is given in the sample code so who can help me to convert this code to R code. Thanks.

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics',
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'covid-193.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'cc818ada02msh65ebe8a8658d181p130600jsn1ee371ee7fbe'
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: The docs for [`httr`](https://httr.r-lib.org/) (on which `rvest` depends) have some good examples to adding headers (with `add_headers`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`httr::add_headers`](https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/add_headers.html) just requires *"named header values"*. So you just need

```r
library(httr)

GET("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics")
# Response [https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics]
#   Date: 2020-03-29 05:02
#   Status: 401
#   Content-Type: application/json
#   Size: 139 B

GET("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics",
    add_headers(`x-rapidapi-host`='covid-193.p.rapidapi.com',
                `x-rapidapi-key`= 'cc818ada02msh65ebe8a8658d181p130600jsn1ee371ee7fbe'))
# Response [https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics]
#   Date: 2020-03-29 05:02
#   Status: 200
#   Content-Type: application/json
#   Size: 37.9 kB
```

The first response is "401 Unauthorized", the second is "200 Success". BTW, if that API key is important to you, you might want to revoke it now that the rest of the world has it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new about api with r. ı tried all the combinations but got error. I think i used " instead of '. Thanks again. it worked.

Comment: In R, there is no difference between `'` and `"`, so perhaps there was something else wrong. Good luck!

Comment: Yes. Probably. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried with " it does not work for "add_headers" parameters. For the GET parameters is does not important. interesting.